# App store is asking me to sign in with my old AccountID

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore

I'm working on macOS 10.13.4. When I open the App Store and attempt to update my apps which need updating, I am prompted to sign in to my apple account. However, it's prompting me to sign into foo@yahoo.com without giving me the option of changing that ID.

About a year ago, I modified my account to use a different email address, foo@gmail.com. It's the same account - just with an updated ID. How can I modify the ID within the app store?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried typing the current password for your new account with your old Apple ID? In the past, that has worked for me.

Comment: I did but unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: Had the same issue on my iPhone. I created a new Apple ID and it works fine, but I also had to create a new gmail account which was problematic until I got used to using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have originally downloaded the apps while logged in with your old Apple ID, than to update it will ask old Apple ID and password. To fix this issue, delete the installed app, login with your current Apple ID and download the app again. This would solve the problem.

Comment: The apps prompting me for a password without letting me change my user id are: IMovie, Pages, Keynote, and Numbers.  Are you saying I should remove all of these and then re-install them?

Comment: yes they were downloaded using old apple id so you have to remove and reinstall them to use with current apple id @Ben